# NPM - Getting error when trying to run the npm install command (webpack and babel-loader)

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, npm-install, babel-loader

When I am trying to run this command **npm install** like I would usual stuff, I get these errors on this project that I am working on currently:

[image]

I have tried to fallback to **Node.js v14.15.4** version to see if it will be fixed, but it would not. Anybody has any clue how to do this?

**What I think:**

- Maybe the version of the Node.js is not compatible
- My npm version is 8.1.4, so maybe that can cause the problem
- Problem with npm in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project wants webpack 3.10 and babel-loader 6.4.1, but babel-loader 6.4.1 wants webpack 2. Upgrade babel-loader? (specifically to 7.x, not 8.x/latest, if you need webpack 3)

Comment: That helped, but now I am getting this error. `Could not resolve dependency: peer webpack@"^2.2.0" from extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.2`

Comment: @Samke11 That package (extract-text-webpack-plugin) is deprecated:  `Deprecated. Please use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin` ([source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-text-webpack-plugin))

Comment: Yes, I am aware it is, but this project is old and I can not change almost anything or to be precise, to upgrade it

Comment: @Samke11 Then upgrade extract-text-webpack-plugin to latest (2.1.2 doesn't support webpack 3) (or figure out why you have dependencies for webpack 2 but your package.json wants webpack 3?)

Comment: I fixed it. Just deleted the `extract-text-webpack-plugin` from `package.json` and the install it after everything else finished installing. Thank you for helping me!